# How to create clusters within a cluster in python parallel processing?

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I am working on a task which requires parallel process at multiple stages.

My question is:

I have four data sets. I have written a function to process those 4 data sets.
To process those 4 data sets parallelly, I created 4 clusters and then sent 4 data sets to 4 clusters. Again I want to split each cluster into 4 clusters as I have to do `group by` operation. I written a code to process the above problem. But it was throwing me an error. Here is my sample code.

```
def applyParallel(dfGrouped, func):
    retLst = Parallel(n_jobs=2, verbose=10)(delayed(func)(group) for name, group in dfGrouped)
    return pd.concat(retLst)

# This is the function to do group by parallel processing.
def new(x):
    tsc_out = applyParallel(x.groupby(gbcols), custum_func) 

def f1():
    from joblib import Parallel, delayed
    Parallel(n_jobs=4)(delayed(new)(i) for i in range(4)) #4 data sets
```

This function is running properly if we create clusters at one time only. It is not working if we try to split each cluster into multiple clusters.
In my case I need to create total `20` cluster.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your case correctly, you can do something like this using charm4py's pool
of workers (see https://charm4py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pool.html for more
information). For example:

```
from charm4py import charm

def applyParallel(dfGrouped, func):
    retLst = charm.pool.map(func, [group for name, group in dfGrouped], ncores=2)
    return pd.concat(retLst)

# This is the function to do group by parallel processing
def new(x):
    tsc_out = applyParallel(x.groupby(gbcols), custom_func)

def f1(args):
    charm.pool.map(new, [i for i in range(4)], ncores=4, allow_nested=True)
    exit()

charm.start(f1)
```

Using the pool of workers, you can start tasks (which I think is the same as what you call clusters) specifying how many cores
you want running a given set of tasks. Although I think in your case you could
just leave `ncores=-1` and let charm4py schedule the tasks using the available cores.

It will also work if you have tasks start other tasks (if you use `allow_nested=True`).

One thing to note is that when you start a program with charm4py, you will specify how many processes to launch
(you can even launch processes on multiple hosts and the application can use
all of them simultaneously). So, for example, if you have 8 cores and want to leverage all of
them, launch the program with 8 processes.